# Displaying different groups for each children term in one page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm using Taxonomy View to display all nodes belonging to a term.

If it is a parent term, all nodes belonging to the children term are displayed (I've set depth>0).

However the nodes are displayed all together. While I would like them to be displayed in different groups (one for each children term).

Thanks

Comment: Would you be willing to write a module for that? It is -somehow- doable in views, with ugly theme-hacks, but can be done cleanly in a module. If so, I can help write that module in an *answer*.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but I asked a similar question about grouping in views recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512582/taxonomy-view-with-nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick, the solution proposed at [Taxonomy view with nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512582/taxonomy-view-with-nodes/3513135#3513135) is what you need, as bkildow pointed out.

The only difference is that instead of adding "Taxonomy: Term" you need to add "Taxonomy: All terms" as a field. The rest of the fields are up to you, but at least a title linked to the full node is advisable.

For the View options you can choose whatever format works for you, just don't forget to set the grouping field to "Taxonomy: All terms" (or whatever label you may want to give it in the field properties)