# Taxonomy view with nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, taxonomy

Using Drupal 6, I'm trying to create a page with views that shows something like the following:

> -Taxonomy Term 1
>   -- Title and description of a node that contains this term
>   -- Title and description of a node that contains this term
>   -Taxonomy Term 2
>   -- Title and description of a node that contains this term
>   -- Title and description of a node that contains this term
>   -Taxonomy Term 3
>   -- Title and description of a node that contains this term
>   -- Title and description of a node that contains this term

So basically when I go to this page, I see taxonomy terms of a particular vocabulary listed out as titles, and underneath I see the title and description of all nodes that have this taxonomy term.

Is this possible to do with views? Or if not, Is there another module that can help me? Or should I be rolling my own for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible, and here's how.

1. Create a new view and make "Node" the base table.
2. Add a "Taxonomy: Vocabulary" filter for your taxonomy vocabulary, if you would only like to list the terms from a specific vocabulary.
3. Add a "Taxonomy: Term" field, and have it excluded from display.
4. Add a "Node: Title" field.
5. Add a "Taxonomy: Term" sorting option. It's up to you whether you want it to sort ascending or descending.
6. For the View's style, select "Unformatted", and in the options that come after that, select your "Taxonomy: Term" field as the grouping field.
7. Make sure you have the "Limit Rows" set to unlimited.
8. Make a page display, give it a URL.

That's it. The key point here is the "Grouping Field" part; that's what will group all of the nodes by the taxonomy terms assigned to them. Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent, thank you! The Grouping Field is what was getting me. Great answer.

Comment: Can I make this work also with grids ? I need to use a grid and not unformatted style. thanks

Comment: Yes, the "grids" view style also appears to have the "grouping field" option, as well as the other styles.