# Best practices to list books and books childs with hierarchical style in Views

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, hierarchy

Im developing a website about travels.

My needs is to build a view that output:

```
France Guide
- Guide to Paris*
-- Hostels in Paris
- Guide to Lyon*
- Guide to Hostels in France
Ireland Guide
- Dublin*
-- Hostels in Dublin
- Cork*
Italy Guide
- Rome*
- Florence*
```

The nodes with the asterisk * has a location field, and i need to show them in a gmap view.

Every title should be linked to his node.

The problem is: how to represent this hierarchy with Views?

I've tried to use the book module, so i have a 'Guide' book, then 'France Guide', 'Italy Guide' and 'Ireland Guide' as 'Guide' childs, then 'Guide to Paris' as a 'France guide' child, and so on, but seem like Views allow to list the item parents, not the childs.

I've tried to use Taxonomy to, building a vocabulary with the same book structure... but stuck again.

I have the completely freedom oh how to structure this, the importants things are:

1. Users who will insert contents should indicate the hierarchy in a simple way (the book outline is perfect)
2. It has to be done with views, becose i need the gmap view, to show a marker on france and into the tooltip all the relative guides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hierarchy with taxonomy and views. Check out this question: [Taxonomy view with nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512582/taxonomy-view-with-nodes). I'm not sure if it would be easy to represent anything deeper than the example shows. Also googling around, I found this module: http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy which could possibly work, although I have never tried it.